# Role of expected loss of the best forecast in decision theory

Tags: decision-theory

Suppose we have a random variable $Y$ with an unknown distribution $P$. We model it with a distribution $Q$. We are asked to make a point forecast under some type of loss $L$. We choose the loss minimizing $\hat y=\arg\min_y\int L(s-y) dQ(s)$ as our forecast. I am interested in the quantity

- $\int L(s-\hat y) dP(s)$ which is the expected loss of this point forecast w.r.t. the true distribution of $Y$

and to a lesser extent in

- $\int L(s-\hat y) dQ(s)$ which is the expected loss of this point forecast w.r.t. our model.

**Question:** Does any of these quantities have a name and do they play a role in any of the major decision theoretic frameworks?

I would like to learn more about their roles and intepretations; connections to economic literature are welcome.

(More generally, I am interested in decision making under uncertainty when $P$ and $Q$ do not coincide and am looking for theory/theories that account(s) for this in detail. References are welcome.)

Comment: All theory is on P. How can you build a theory on Q if it's not known? P represents what you know about Q, and you work with what you know. Also your liberal usage of "certain" and "expected" is confusing, especially in the title

Comment: @Aksakal, updated to address your comment. Also, we need theories that help us model reality, not theories that are easy to develop. If the theory ignores P (no connection to reality), I wonder what its use is.

Comment: Q doesn't ignore the reality. It approximates it. It's better than having nothing at all, which is your P (unknown)

Comment: @Aksakal, to say that reality is nothing at all in an interesting perspective. However, if Q approximates reality, then there is a relationship between Q and P, and it is precisely this relationship that makes Q valuable in solving the problem at hand. Without a relationship to P, Q would be of no practical use. In any case, thanks for your comments and I look forward to some references.

Answer (score 1):

A good start would be a couple of papers by Tilmann Gneiting, e.g. [Gneiting (2011), "Quantiles as Optimal Point Forecasts", *International Journal of Forecasting*](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ijforecast.2009.12.015), or also [Gneiting (2011), "Making and Evaluating Point Forecasts", *JASA*](https://doi.org/10.1198/jasa.2011.r10138). He is mainly writing about $Q$ and about minimizing the expected loss for various loss functions $L$ (although not so much about the loss itself). I have an accepted commentary on the M4 forecasting competition in the *IJF* where I make similar points to argue that evaluating the *same* point prediction with *different* loss functions ("error measures" in forecasting terminology) - which is very common in forecasting - makes little sense.

The pretty much accepted nomenclature among forecasters for the loss is "loss", and for the optimal point forecast is "optimal point forecast". (Sorry.) I am unfortunately not aware of any work specifically on the expected loss under the true density $P$.

I would be interested in any literature on the questions you raise, especially anything that relates the loss under the true $P$ to $Q$ or some measure of distance between the two (Kullback-Leibler looks like it might figure here).

Comment: Thanks for your edit and answer. I have read those papers a while ago and I will check them again, but as you indicate, his focus is a little off w.r.t. my interest. My problem is that I am coming from a forecasting background and trying to enter the territory of decision theory where I lack a firm footing. I was wondering, for example, whether the quantities I mention could be related to the notions of uncertainty, risk or other related terms used in some version of decision theory.